# Can I "Install [a full version of] Qt [which I can build against] via the conan package manager"?

Tags: c++, qt, conan, build-system, qt6

I am reading this: https://www.qt.io/blog/installing-qt-via-conan-package-manager

And its header suggests, that I can **Install Qt via the conan package manager.**
And yet after I finish the steps laid out, I end up with a directory that looks like this:

```cpp
~/Library/Qt  ls -l                                                                                                                                                                                ✔ 
total 724
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon   7279 Mar 18 20:17 activate.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon   6154 Mar 18 20:17 activate.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    299 Mar 18 16:51 ci-linux-webassembly-x86_64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    467 Mar 18 16:51 ci-linux-x86_64-gcc
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    260 Mar 18 16:51 ci-linux-x86_64-gcc-debug-developer
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon     32 Mar 18 16:51 ci-macos-ios-arm64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    446 Mar 18 16:51 ci-macos-universal-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    299 Mar 18 16:51 ci-macos-webassembly-x86_64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    506 Mar 18 16:51 ci-unix-android-arm64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    506 Mar 18 16:51 ci-unix-android-armv7-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    507 Mar 18 16:51 ci-unix-android-x86_64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    504 Mar 18 16:51 ci-unix-android-x86-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    511 Mar 18 16:51 ci-windows-android-arm64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    511 Mar 18 16:51 ci-windows-android-armv7-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    560 Mar 18 16:51 ci-windows-android-x86_64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    557 Mar 18 16:51 ci-windows-android-x86-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    371 Mar 18 16:51 ci-windows-arm64-msvc2019_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    301 Mar 18 16:51 ci-windows-webassembly-x86_64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    307 Mar 18 16:51 ci-windows-webassembly-x86_64-clang-debug
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    484 Mar 18 16:51 ci-windows-x86_64-mingw
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    455 Mar 18 16:51 ci-windows-x86_64-msvc2019_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    475 Mar 18 16:51 ci-windows-x86_64-msvc2019_64-developer
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon  75609 Mar 18 20:17 conanbuildinfo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon  18333 Mar 18 22:04 conaninfo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon 338817 Mar 18 22:04 conan.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon   2630 Mar 18 16:51 conanmanifest.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon  12334 Mar 18 20:17 deactivate.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon   9580 Mar 18 20:17 deactivate.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon   3628 Mar 18 20:13 deploy_manifest.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon  27043 Mar 18 20:17 environment.ps1.env
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon  27584 Mar 18 20:17 environment.sh.env
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon  22657 Mar 18 22:04 graph_info.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    416 Mar 18 16:51 linux-webassembly-x86_64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    709 Mar 18 16:51 linux-x86_64-gcc
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    363 Mar 18 16:51 linux-x86_64-gcc-debug-developer
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    454 Mar 18 16:51 macos-ios-arm64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    586 Mar 18 16:51 macos-universal-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    416 Mar 18 16:51 macos-webassembly-x86_64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    891 Mar 18 20:10 my_app_depencies.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    822 Mar 18 16:51 unix-android-arm64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    824 Mar 18 16:51 unix-android-armv7-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    820 Mar 18 16:51 unix-android-x86_64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    814 Mar 18 16:51 unix-android-x86-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    860 Mar 18 16:51 windows-android-arm64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    862 Mar 18 16:51 windows-android-armv7-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    906 Mar 18 16:51 windows-android-x86_64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    858 Mar 18 16:51 windows-android-x86-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    561 Mar 18 16:51 windows-arm64-msvc2019_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    485 Mar 18 16:51 windows-webassembly-x86_64-clang
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    634 Mar 18 16:51 windows-webassembly-x86_64-clang-debug
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    610 Mar 18 16:51 windows-x86_64-mingw
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    543 Mar 18 16:51 windows-x86_64-msvc2019_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    651 Mar 18 16:51 windows-x86_64-msvc2019_64-developer
```

And I do not see any directory or any hint that there is a path to a version of Qt that I can now use in a kit.

Ostensibly, the file that I am interested in is this

```cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon anon    416 Mar 18 16:51 linux-webassembly-x86_64-clang
```

```cpp
[settings]
    os=Emscripten
    arch=wasm
    compiler=clang
    compiler.version=10
    compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
    build_type=Release
[options]
qtbase:release=True
qtbase:shared=False
qtbase:qt_host_path=$QT_HOST_PATH
qtbase:nomake=examples;tests
qtbase:cmake_args_qtbase="-DQT_QMAKE_TARGET_MKSPEC=wasm-emscripten"
*:cmake_args_leaf_module=""
[build_requires]
[env]
CONAN_CMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja
```

Because I want a version of Qt WebAssembly that I can build against ( Compiling it from source has been nothing but frustration )

I don't get it.

I assume that **Install Qt via the Conan Package Manager** means something completely different than actually installing an instance of Qt that I can build against.

If that is true, then what exactly am I supposed to use these files for? Does it expect for me to already have the version of Qt to build against, already present on my machine?